# Установка битов

Tags: c++

Немножко просел по побитовым операциям.
Не совсем понимаю, как, допустим, `установить 7 бит в 1`.

```
int N;
cin >> N;
N |= (1 << (31-7));
cout << N;
```

Тобишь сдвигаем на `31-7` и пишем в первый бит.
Или я не правильно что-то понимаю?
Верно ли мое решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Биты нумеруются справа на лево, начиная с нуля.

Поэтому установить седьмой бит можно следующим образом:

```
N |= (1 << 7);
```

А сбросить, соответственно, следующим:

```
N &= (0xFFFE << 7); //для 32-битного N
```

Comment: "установить седьмой бит ..." Вы бы уточнили, какой номер у вас имеет самый правый бит. А то может вовсе и не седьмой устанавливаете)

Comment: @wololo, уточнил. Хотя, если честно, не встречался с нумерацией с 1.